# Explanation of sentence

Tags: american-english, mathematics, programming

I don't understand this sentence.... I know the meaning of all words except distinct... I looked in dictionary.. but I don't understand..:/

Output the **number of distinct values when considered MOD 42**, one per line for each test case.

Comment: [definition of distinct](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/distinct)

Comment: I've voted to close as General Reference, but I will point out that it's more often *the number of **discrete** values*, or in less elevated contexts, *the number of **different** values*. To my mind, *distinct* here is a bad choice, being neither the "academic/formal" nor the "popular vernacular" version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a programming question than an English question so I suspect it will soon be closed, but for what it's worth:

As Andrew and Will note, "distinct" means "different". So the problem is saying that you are to find the set of values -- I presume where you get the "raw" set is explained earlier in the problem -- and then take each value mod 42 (i.e. the remainder when you divide by 42), and output a list of only the distinct values found, i.e. if the same number shows up more than once, only output it once.

Answer (score 0):

[Dictionary reference](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?query=distinct&title=21st&sourceid=Mozilla-search)

Separate; different.

In the specific example, you discard duplicated numbers. The number of distinct values in the set `{1,1,2,2,3,4,56}` is five: `{1,2,3,4,56}`

Comment: thanks... http://www.codechef.com/problems/NSIT13 ..pls look here... I don't undertand what I need to do with number here..:)